# Is there a "do nothing" command in LaTeX?

Tags: renewcommand

I'm defining it like this for myself:

```
\newcommand\nothing[1]{#1}
```

Maybe the same already exists in LaTeX and I can just use it?

PS. The purpose of this is to highlight certain parts of the `.tex` document for another post-processor (spell checker). In reality, my command's name is `\nospellcheck`.

Comment: There are `\@firstofone` and `\@iden` but of course with `@` in their name. No user macros AFAIK.

Comment: For which purpose do you want it or need it?

Comment: `\relax` can be a do-nothing command.  `\empty` expands to nothing.  Adapting to your syntax, `\newcommand\nothing{}` takes no argument.  The command you present does something...it absorbs an argument and echoes it.

Comment: How about `\newcommand\donothing[1]{Donald Trump}`?

Comment: Your `\donothing` command just echos the following argument. Is that what you want? Then `\relax` should do the job. PS: it takes no arguments so it does nothing. Do you really want it to gobble the argument?

Comment: What does "do nothing" mean? Your `\donothing`-command does not nothing: It strips the outermost level of matching curly braces if present. Both `\donothing a` and `\donothing {a}` yield `a`, without surrounding curly braces.  Your `\donothing`-command is the same as `\@firstofone` and it could probably be called "just-spit-out--the-grabbed-argument"-command. `\empty`/`\@empty` could be called the "grab-no-argument-and-expand-to-nothing"-command. `\@gobble` could be called the "gobble-an-argument"-command. `\relax` could be called the "go-to-TeX's-stomach-but-trigger-no-action-there"-command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any time you absorb an argument using the standard approach, you are potentially losing information...for example, a leading space before the absorbed argument. Another example is if the argument absorbed is a single token, you won't know if it originally had braces on it or not. As a result of these uncertainties, I tend not to consider argument absorption as a "do nothing" command.

In the MWE below, the active-`Q` is set to the OP's definition of `\nothing`.  It is employed twice in the 2nd line.  In the first instance, one loses the space because of argument absorption.  In the 2nd instance, one loses the braces around `a`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\nothing[1]{#1}
\begin{document}
\catcode`\Q=\active

\letQ\nothing

a b\detokenize{{a}}

aQ b\detokenize\expandafter{Q{a}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A better "do nothing" command would be

```
\newcommand\nothing{}
```

or, equivalently,

```
\let\nothing\empty
```

However, even that is not foolproof.  Any new token introduced, even `\empty`, can interfere if it becomes the target of an expansion or absorption.

Here's such an example where the introduction of the simplified `\nothing` still changes the result (though, in this case, the `\nothing` improves the result):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\let\nothing\empty
\begin{document}
\def\z|#1|{\detokenize\expandafter{#1}}

\z|{abc}|

\z|\nothing{abc}|
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note: this exact situation was a bug I just discovered yesterday in my tokcycle package when text is *escaped* from the cycle when placed between `|` delimiters.  It lost the braces if the escaped text was a single brace group, in the manner shown in the first line above.  My fix, which I am about to submit to CTAN, amounts to using the technique with `\empty`, shown on the second line, which will retain those braces.

Comment: I never imagined a question about an identity command would lead to such a long, philosophical elaboration. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler writing `tokcycle`, which tries to absorb an input stream token by token without losing information, gave me a huge respect and awareness for these sort of unanticipated interactions.  Even so, it is certainly not without pathological cases, especially when you throw in active characters, catcode changes, cat-6 tokens, implicit grouping, implicit spaces, etc.  The most interesting anomaly is the active token whose charcode is no longer active!

Comment: @Gaussler Now make it an "active **implicit space** token whose charcode is no longer active" and you can begin to appreciate the difficulties.

Comment: I certainly do appreciate “do nothing” commands. In fact, in preparation for the age of tagged PDFs and semantic math markup, I have started using a command `\invmult` for an invisible multiplication symbol. It’s not quite `\newcommand\invmult{}`, but it’s close to that. `;-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Perhaps you mean the "discretionary multiplication" macro, `\let\invmult\*`

Comment: As far as I remember, `\*` becomes `\times` at line breaks, not `\cdot`. Research-level mathematics never uses `\times` for ordinary multiplication. Plus, I would never want it to become visible at line breaks. (And in reality, I used a `semantic`-based construction. This also allows me to use `stripsemantex` for later removing it from my document when preparing it for publication. Also, I program it so that it can also be used as an *n*-ary operation, so that e.g. `\invmult{\va,\vb,...,\vz}` prints *ab⋯z*.) `;-)`

Comment: Well, there you go @Gaussler...if "research-level mathematics **never** uses `\times` for ordinary multiplication", then sounds like it's time to redefine `\*` to suit your needs.  It takes fewer keystrokes than `\invmult`.

Comment: I actually did plan to ask in here about how to do that, but never pulled myself together. But again, I can’t think of a situation where I would be using such a “maybe `\cdot`” command. The number of keystrokes has never really been a problem to me . I can type “`\invmult`” in about 1.2 seconds. `;-)`